# Logic App always takes 30s to read empty service bus queue

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App which has a "Get messages from service bus queue (peek lock)" action. I frequently expect this action to return without any messages so I check the length of the response to see if it's 0 and go and do some work to populate the queue if that's the case.

My problem is that the action to read the service bus takes 30s when the queue is empty. This causes a significant delay with giving a response to the Logic App caller.

How can I make this Action timeout sooner?

I have looked at the Action settings and there is one described

> **Timeout**
>
> Limit the maximum duration an asynchronous pattern may take. Note: this does not alter the request timeout of a single request.

I'm not entirely sure what this means, but I would have thought it is how long the async polling for a response should continue for.

Changing this value to PT10S had no effect.

I suspect the problem is that the call to the Service Bus is a long poll that is hardcoded to timeout after 30s - can anyone confirm or refute this?

Is there any way to reduce this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Timeout**
>
> Limit the maximum duration an asynchronous pattern may take. Note: this does not alter the request timeout of a single request.

This setting does not impact the action duration, as the Service Bus Get Actions and Triggers implement a single http request (Polling the queue inside) as opposed to an async call back.

> I suspect the problem is that the call to the Service Bus is a long poll that is hardcoded to timeout after 30s - can anyone confirm or refute this?

Based on my understanding on the connector, Get Service Bus Actions and Triggers implement a long polling of 30 seconds, which you cannot change.

**Update** In addition to using an Azure Function as you suggested below, you could abstract the `GetMessages` call in a Nested Logic App which implements parallel branches. One branch would read from the queue, while the other one would return a timeout response if the main branch takes longer than your threshold. 
The pattern is explained here http://mikaelsand.se/timeout-and-parallel-branches-in-logic-apps/

HTH

Comment: Thanks Paco, I guess a sensible way around this is to implement a Function that returns the Count of messages on the queue so that the LA knows whether to read or go do some work. Any other suggestions? (great blog BTW!)

Comment: That's one option, I added one more as an update to my answer. (Thanks mate, I'm glad you like it :D)

Comment: Thanks Paco, that's a clever (if a bit complicated) solution. I also found this issue raised on the Feedback Forum https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/35244421--service-bus-connector should anyone else wish to vote for making this configurable.

Comment: It'd be great if they allow us to configure the poll duration (1 to 120 secs). In the meantime, you have 2 work arounds. Whichever suits you best :)